# What's the best way to complete links on a certain WordPress Page with everything after the slug?

Tags: php, wordpress, mod-rewrite

I'm looking for the optimal approach to replace all links on a WordPress page with the segment that follows the page's slug. Currently, I'm encountering an issue where accessing the page with an additional URL segment leads to unintended redirects. Here's a relevant code snippet:

For instance, I want to transform links from https://every-outgoing-link-on-the-page.com to https://every-outgoing-link-on-the-page.com/username, where "username" corresponds to the portion accessed with the specific page "/r" as in https://my-page.com/r/username.

```
function custom_username_links_modify_links($content) {
    global $post;

    // Check if the current page is the selected landing page
    $landing_page_id = get_option('custom_username_links_landing_page');
    if ($post->ID == $landing_page_id) {
        // Seeking advice on the most effective approach
        return $content;
    }

    // Continue with link modifications for other pages
    $permalink = get_permalink($post->ID);
    $current_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $slug = str_replace($permalink, '', $current_url);
    $modified_content = preg_replace('/href=["\'](https?:\/\/[^"\'\s]+)["\']/i', 'href="$1/' . trim($slug, '/') . '"', $content);

    return $modified_content;
}
```

I'd appreciate insights on the best practice to address this situation. Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Maybe the [WordPress stack](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) would be a better fit for this question?

Comment: @MrWhite thanks. Should I delete this question then?